# Long text in v-autocomplete

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I need the v-autocomplete component to show the full text of the selected element.

In the selection it appears correctly:

[image]

But once selected it is shown like this, I don't know that the full text does not appear:

[image]

Comment: Could your share your code?

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1

Maybe you want to use the `selection` slot of the `v-autocomplete` and split your value into parts for better reading.

```html
<v-autocomplete
  v-model="value"
  :items="items"
  dense
  filled
  label="Filled"
>
  <template v-slot:selection="{ item }">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column"> 
      <span>First</span> <!-- or e.g. item.fullname -->
      <span>Second</span> <!-- or e.g. item.address -->
    </div>
  </template>
</v-autocomplete>
```

Will result in:
[image]

### Solution 2

Or you could use `word-break: break-all;` like

```css
.v-autocomplete .v-select__selections {
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Solution 2, it didn't work for me. The 1 works, but I would like the extra blank line to not appear.

Comment: I think it has to do with this: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/1691 , but still I don't know how to solve it.